# I do not understand why I get this error?

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

Why do I always get an error on myfunc() is not defined?

```
<button onclick = "myfunc();">submit</button>
<script src="script.js">
   function myfunc(){
     let person = {
       name: document.getElementById("demo");
     }
     alert(person.name);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: you also have a ; inside an object declaration

Comment: @imvain2 Having the code below isn't a problem, since the function isn't called immedateily, it's called when the user clicks.

Comment: Get rid of the `;` after `document.getElementById("demo")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a basic fact, your script gets ignored if that script tag has an `src` attribute

[image]

Solution: make a second `script` tag with no src attribute.

```
<button onclick="myfunc();">submit</button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
   function myfunc(){
     let person = {
       name: document.getElementById("demo")
     }
     alert("it works");
   }
</script>
```

Comment: How can I alert the name of what the user puts inside the text box

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky i edited

Comment: Actually got everything resolved, thank you!